# Colorbox HTML5 video display on iPad

Tags: jquery, ios, ipad, html5-video, colorbox

I'm trying to display HTML5 video tags through an inline Colorbox but have been unable to get it working on the iPad. The jQuery I'm using is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#openColorbox").colorbox({
    inline:true, 
    width:"80%", 
    height:"auto", 
    href:"#video"
  });
});
```

Here is a JSFiddle example of the issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/lightstrike/pKUJK/

There are two issues I've been having on the iPad:

1. The video that displays in the Colorbox is black and has no controls *(very important)*
2. Clicking on text to trigger the Colorbox doesn't work but clicking on an image does *(less important)*

As a control for any other issues that might be going on, I also created a JSFiddle that just has the HTML5 video, which works fine on the iPad:
http://jsfiddle.net/lightstrike/XHEWe/

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you considered disabling Colorbox on touch devices?
2. It looks like Mobile Safari doesn't like click events on `<p>` elements. Change it to something like `<a href="#">`. You may need to get more specific with you jQuery selector as well, `$("#openColorbox > a")`. But then if you do that, for some reason Colorbox doesn't display the video... I've never had much luck with Colorbox's inline.